# how can i improve on my convnet performance with small dataset

Tags: machine-learning

I have a very small image data set (about 8 images). I am aware that my model can result in overfitting with a small dataset and I wanted some ideas on ways to deal with situations where the dataset is as small as stated above.

Comment: You can always collect more data or is it an restriction for you?

Comment: there is a restriction

Answer (score 1):

The best way to deal with this kind of issue is to use Image Augmentation. There are several libraries present which provides this like opencv2, keras, scikit-image. The basic idea behind image augmentation is to artificially create more images from one image by introducing certain changes in the data like rotating the image, blurring it at certain sides, zooming in/out on images, changing the coloring, flipping the image and a lot more. You can create 10x, 20x, 40x, etc images from one image.

This method will help you generate more images but remember that 8 images is a very small data and these new augmented images will in one way or another will have, to some extent, similar features to that of the original.

Comment: do you recommend using GANs to help with this? Also, do you think transfer learning would improve things?

Comment: The concept behind transfer learning is to get a pretrained model that is capable of detecting features in your data and then that model is fine tuned on your data. Since you do not have enough data to train a good model from scratch, transfer learning might help things. GANs can help too as they are kind of an advance method of image augmentation.